# Dimensions of tensor product

Tags: tensor-products

I am confused over dimensions in tensor product.

I have a tensor $A$ with dimensions $m \times n \times 3 $. I want to keep values for only first slice ($m\times n$)  of $A$ and make other slices as $0$.

$[1,0,0]*A$ does it well. It is still an $m\times n\times 3$ tensor.

Now, I have a tensor $B$ with dimensions $m\times n\times 4$. I want to again keep only the first slice intact, make other slices $0$, in addition, make it an $m\times n\times 3$ tensor.

I tried $[1,0,0,0]*B$, which is giving a $m\times n\times 4$ tensor with desired values. But I want to discard the last slice. Want to do it using tensor multiplication only. (And my ultimate goal is to divide the values of the first slice into two equal parts, and put them on first and the second slice, that I can work out after I am clear about the multiplication functionality of tensors.)

Also, in 2 dimensional matrices, multiplying $A_{m\times n}*B_{n\times p }$ gives $C_{m\times p}$.
But in tensor multiplication, $(1\times 3)*(m\times n\times 3)$ is giving back $m\times n\times 3$. Can someone explain why?

Comment: This is not a mathematics question. This is a question about how to use a specific computer software. What are you using? Maple, Mathematica, Matlab, numpy, tensorflow,... There are MANY ways to do tensor computations...

Comment: ok. I thought * is mathematical multiplication, independent of software. I am using numpy.

Answer (score 1):

**For matrices** (i.e., rank 2 tensors), there are multiple things that could be called "multiplication". For example:

- matrix-multiplication $C_{i,j}=\sum_k A_{i,k}B_{k,j}$ (where $C$ is a matrix)
- component-wise multiplication $C_{i,j} = A_{i,j}B_{i,j}$ (where $C$ is a matrix)
- an inner product $C=\sum_{i,j}A_{i,j}B_{i,j}$ (where $C$ is a single number)
- an outer product $C_{ijkl} = A_{i,j}B_{k,l}$ (where $C$ is a rank-4 tensor)

of these, the matrix multiplication is the most common one (at least in mathematics. In data-analysis, the component-wise is probably used more often). Therefore it is usually denoted simply as $AB$.

**For larger tensors** there are even more possibilities, and no single one is really canonical. So you have to think about what you want. In numpy, there are different methods depending on what you want:

- `A*B`: This does either component-wise (+broadcasting), or matrix-multiplication. It depends on the type of `A` and `B` ("ndarray" and "matrix" are different types in numpy). "matrix" objects are a subclass of "ndarray", so they inherit all the attributes and methods of ndarrays. The main advantage (and a source of confusion) of numpy matrices is that they provide a convenient notation for matrix multiplication: if `A` and `B` are matrices, then `A*B` is their matrix product. If `A` and `B` are just ndarrays, then `A*B` is their component-wise product.
- [`A.dot(B)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)
- [`numpy.multi_dot(...)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html)
- [`numpy.vdot(A,B)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vdot.html)
- ... (not gonna list them all here)...
- [`numpy.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html): This is the most powerful/flexible one. You can do all of the others (and more) with this.

You have to read the documentation and figure out which operation you want.